# What should I do about incoming connections if my ISP uses CGNAT?

Tags: p2p

Unfortunately, my ISP uses CGNAT, so port forwarding doesn't work. What should I do? Can I have incoming connections (since I want to open them) and how? Would a VPN help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to achieve this is by using an [overlay network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_network) like [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)), [i2p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P) or [Yggdrasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil). Check out how to set up [Tor](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md) and [i2p](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/i2p.md) with Bitcoin Core.

There are other services that let you bypass a NAT, like some VPNs or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). But beware that (i) they may limit your reach and pick what ports you'll use (ii) they can see what you're doing, so bad for privacy.

> Would a VPN help?

Some VPNs might let you accept connections through it, but most of the commercial ones don't.